# Find Null or Zero Values in MongoDB Nested Array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Assume my mongo collection is named my_collection. An example of one record in my_collection looks like:

```
{ 
   "_id" : ObjectId("1"),
   "field1" : "blah",
   "field2" : {
      "1" : "28",
      "2" : null,
      "3" : "0"
      }
}
```

Some records might have a null or zero value(s) in "field2", and others might not.

I need to find a record where the key in "field2" is any value ("1"-whatever), and the value for that key is either null or equal to zero.

How do I write a statement using findOne to do that?

Comment: `field2` is an array or an object?

Comment: I'd say field2 is an object, and it's value is an array

Comment: There is no array in your example. Please provide valid sample data.

Comment: Apologies, I assumed the data underneath "field2" would've been referred to as an array. I removed that language from the question. Still, the example record I gave is an accurate representation of how it's being stored.

Answer (score 0):

[MongoDB's findOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/mongodb/actions/collection.findOne/) can use nested objects and arrays.

```
db.collection.findOne({
    field2: {
        2: null
    }
})
```

and

```
db.collection.findOne({
    fields: [
        {
            2: null
        }
    ]
})
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to find any record that has a value of null or zero without specifying the key 2 or 3.

Comment: @fjjones88 you can probably just do `[ 0 ]` or `[ null ]`, but I haven't tested it myself.